# program unstable and not quit after joining all threads of vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I m new to multithreading in c++11 and i tried to implement a function similar to thread pool in vector. but the code(primeGenStdThread())is unstable. sometimes, it is able to printout stuff, sometimes cannot. and it 100% fail to quit the program after i join all of them. Could anyone idenitify the problem? thanks alot!

```
std::vector<std::thread> workers;
std::mutex q_mutex;
std::condition_variable condition;
bool stop=false;
bool start=false;
std::queue<std::function<void()>> tasks;

void primeGenStdThread_task(int i);

void primeGenStdThread(){
    for (int i=2; i<100; i++){
        tasks.push([i](){
            primeGenStdThread_task(i);
        });
    }

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        std::cout<<"for i " << i << std::endl;
        workers.push_back(std::thread([](){
            while(true){
                std::function<void()> task;
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(q_mutex);
                    condition.wait(lock, []{
                        return start==true;});
                    std::cout << "thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "task size" << tasks.size()<<std::endl;
                    if(tasks.empty()){
                        start=false;
                        return;
                    }else{
                        task = std::move(tasks.front());
                        tasks.pop(); 
                    }
                }
            task();
            }
        }));
    }

    std::cout<<"work size"<<workers.size()<<std::endl;
    start=true;
    for(std::thread &worker: workers){
        worker.join();
    }
    return;
}

void primeGenStdThread_task(int i){
        for (int j=2; j<i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
            else if (i == j+1)
                ;//std::cout << i << " ";

        }
}
```

Comment: Where are you notifying `condition`?  In cases like this, a debugger that lets you switch threads (for example, gdb) is helpful to figure out where each thread is in its call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally figured out the reason.

just add notifiy_all after setting start to true

and remove start=false in the if statement below.

```
if(tasks.empty()){
    start=false;
    return;
}
```